# Javascript replace special characters

Tags: javascript, replace

Let's say I want to replace this:

```
Test%20Test
```

into this:

```
Test\X20\Test
```

I know this sounds weird but I need for the string to look like that. And I can't get my head around this because of the last backlash. Is there any way with `.replace()` to achieve that? If I wanted just `Test\X20Test` I could easily do `string.replace(/%/g, '\\X');` but I need the backlash after the hexadecimal code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple [capture group](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter) would work.

```
"Test%20Test".replace(/%([0-9A-F]{2})/ig, "\\X$1\\");
```